# Select on MySQL Partitioned table is not selecting the correct partitions

Tags: mysql, select, partitioning

This is regarding MySQL 5.5

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS isup_trace_test (
             id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
             datetime datetime DEFAULT NULL,
             microseconds int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
             opc int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
             dpc int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
             slc int(11) NOT NULL,
             operation varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
             release_text varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
             release_code int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
             calling varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
             nrn varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
             called varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
             cic int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
             message text,
             filename varchar(100) NOT NULL,
             PRIMARY KEY (id,datetime),
             UNIQUE KEY opc (opc,dpc,cic,operation,datetime,microseconds),
             KEY indice (datetime,microseconds,operation,cic,calling,called),
             KEY cic_datetime (cic,datetime,microseconds),
             KEY calling (calling),
             KEY called (called),
             KEY both_a_and_b (datetime,calling),
             KEY by_release_text (release_text),
             KEY by_release_code (release_code),
             KEY operation (datetime,operation),
             KEY per_opc (datetime,opc,dpc,operation),
             KEY for_search (cic,operation,datetime),
             KEY for_search_2 (datetime,calling,operation),
             KEY for_search_3 (datetime,called,operation),
             KEY search_1 (opc,dpc,cic,operation,datetime),
             KEY por_fecha (datetime),
             KEY tata (datetime,opc,dpc),
             KEY datetime_calling_called_operation (datetime,calling,called,operation),
             KEY filename (filename)
           ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
           PARTITION BY LIST( HOUR(datetime) )(
               PARTITION p00 VALUES IN (0)  ,
               PARTITION p01 VALUES IN (1)  DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk2' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk2',
               PARTITION p02 VALUES IN (2)  DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk3' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk3',
               PARTITION p03 VALUES IN (3)  DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk4' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk4',
               PARTITION p04 VALUES IN (4)  DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk5' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk5',
               PARTITION p05 VALUES IN (5)  DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk6' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk6',
               PARTITION p06 VALUES IN (6)  ,                                                        
               PARTITION p07 VALUES IN (7)  DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk2' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk2',
               PARTITION p08 VALUES IN (8)  DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk3' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk3',
               PARTITION p09 VALUES IN (9) DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk4' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk4',
               PARTITION p10 VALUES IN (10) DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk5' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk5',
               PARTITION p11 VALUES IN (11) DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk6' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk6',
               PARTITION p12 VALUES IN (12) ,                                                        
               PARTITION p13 VALUES IN (13) DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk2' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk2',
               PARTITION p14 VALUES IN (14) DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk3' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk3',
               PARTITION p15 VALUES IN (15) DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk4' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk4',
               PARTITION p16 VALUES IN (16) DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk5' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk5',
               PARTITION p17 VALUES IN (17) DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk6' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk6',
               PARTITION p18 VALUES IN (18) ,                                                        
               PARTITION p19 VALUES IN (19) DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk2' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk2',
               PARTITION p20 VALUES IN (20) DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk3' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk3',
               PARTITION p21 VALUES IN (21) DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk4' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk4',
               PARTITION p22 VALUES IN (22) DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk5' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk5',
               PARTITION p23 VALUES IN (23) DATA DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk6' INDEX DIRECTORY='/mnt/disk6'
           )
```

Now the idea of selecting having partitions is for the select to only search the related partitions, I would expect this:

```
EXPLAIN PARTITIONS SELECT * 
FROM isup_trace_test PARTITION (p18)
use index (operation)
WHERE
hour(datetime) = "18" and
DATETIME >= '2013-05-23 18:07:59' AND DATETIME <= '2013-05-23 18:37:59' AND 
operation =  'Release (12)'
```

To return something like:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  isup_trace_test p19 range   operation   operation   56  NULL    24  Using where
```

But in fact it returns:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  isup_trace_test p00,p01,p02,p03,p04,p05,p06,p07,p08,p09,p10,p11,p1...   range   operation   operation   56  NULL    24  Using where
```

meaning it will search ALL partitions.... But it should only search the partition "p19"...

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks!

David

Comment: Your primary key is on the DATETIME column, your partition is on HOUR(DATETIME). I'm guessing this is what confuses the query optimizer.

Comment: @Hazzit . . . Perhaps this can be fixed by explicitly including `hour(datetime)` in the lists for `primary key` and `unique key`.

Comment: Ok, the solution found -following Hazzit's suggestion- was to add an "hour" field and include it in the PRIMARY/UNIQUE KEYs and use that as the partition definition. Of course I would need to include that field when inserting. But it does the job
    hour int(11), <--- new field
    PRIMARY KEY (id,hour ),  <-- PRIMARY KEY
    UNIQUE KEY opc (...,hour ), <-- UNIQUE

And the explain:

    id select_type table partitions type possible_keys key key_len ref rows Extra
    1 SIMPLE isup_trace_test p18 range operation operation 57 NULL 1 Using where

Problem solved! 
Thanks for you help guys!

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go through the documentation of MySQL5.5 then you will find following lines,

"[Pruning can also be applied for tables partitioned on a DATE or DATETIME column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning-pruning.html) when the partitioning expression uses the YEAR() or TO_DAYS() function. In addition, in MySQL 5.5, pruning can be applied for such tables when the partitioning expression uses the TO_SECONDS() function"

It means the function "HOUR()" that you are using for partitioning is not optimized to work with partition pruning.

According to me, there is one more design flaw in your table partitioning.
There is a rule about [using unique constraints with partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations-partitioning-keys-unique-keys.html). In short you can't have a unique constraint on something that you didn't partition by. The reason is that when you insert a record and the uniqueness needs to be checked, we don't want to search through every partition to verify uniqueness. Indexes are local to the partition (global indexes may be implemented in the future). So you can only have a unique constraint if all the columns in the constraint are used in the partitioning expression.

You can decide to drop your primary key if it is really not that important otherwise it will make your inserts into the table.

Hope this helps you to understand the problem.